# Controlling drop down lists in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Form

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a form in a WSS 3.0 site. There are a number of drop-down lists on the form. Is there a way to control the values in one drop-down based on a selected value in a previous drop down?

Answer (score 0):

On post-back you should be able to access the previously selected controls value.

If not, then you might want to try the Control.FindControl method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The cascading dropdowns issue is a big one. There are some solutions that people have built with custom field controls and/or site columsn. Here's a [link](http://www.sharepointsnippets.com/post/2008/11/SharePoint-Cascading-Dropdown---Unlimited-siblings.aspx) to a solution that will let you set up multiple levels of parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this sort of cascaded lookup is big issue indeed.
This thread digs this issue little bit deeper:

[sharepoint cascading drop](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/66/10062444/sharepoint-cascading-drop.aspx)

Cheers